# Video Keywording, captioning and sorting software

Tags: video, software-recommendation

I am looking for suggestions on software to help catalog my growing video library of GoPro MP4 and other (iPhone, dSLR video) files.  This software would be similar to Adobe Bridge or Lightroom - neither of which will write out XMP files for video files to make them portable.

The end result, I hope, is that when I import GoPro footage from a MTB ride where there's a crash, I'm able to keyword & describe the file so I can search the library for MTB, Crash.

I'm on Mac, but ideally the app should be cross platform with Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention Adobe software, what about Prelude and Prelude Live Logger?  It's my understanding that these apps are tailored to ingest, logging, and metadata entry.

Comment: Ideal suggestion, cross platform as well.  It's an option for me that I am looking into as Creative Cloud downloads Prelude while I type this comment.  Without having run the app yet, I already know it will be much more powerful than required for the average GoPro user who just wants to keep track of footage from vacation - and not have a monthly CC membership fee to pay in order to keep track.  

I'm hopeful Prelude will fit the bill for me, but for the average user, likely overkill.

Answer (score 0):

The poor man's alternative is to put all the searchable words you want into the individual video's filename.  Sure, you may have super long titles, but you also get to leverage one of the most robust and fast indexing and search systems out there--that of the operating system (Spotlight, in the case of Mac).